# How to put my ASA 5505 into single router mode so I can restore factory defaults?

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa, system-restore, reset

I'm trying to restore an ASA 5505 to the factory defaults. According to the instructions from several sources (e.g. http://www.mailbeyond.com/restoring-factory-defaults-to-the-cisco-asa5505-firewall-via-the-console) I need to run the following command:

```
ciscoasa(config)#config factory-default
```

But this returns:

```
ERROR: command can only be executed in single router mode
```

The command to put the ASA into single router mode should be:

```
ciscoasa(config)#mode single
```

But this returns:

```
ciscoasa(config)#mode single
                   ^
ERROR: %Invalid input detected at '^' marker
```

Comment: What's your privilege level?  And do you have anything restricting the available command set, like TACACS authorization rules?  What do you get from `show context`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 5505 is not capable of running in multiple context mode. This is probably just a bug. I would:

1. backup your config: `more system:running-config` then save this config to a txt file
2. `wr erase` to erase the startup config
3. `reload` and say no when it asks you to save the current running configuration

Comment: That did the trick. After reload I was able to restore factory defaults. BTW, it's not obvious to a newbie that reload is a command, suggest adding backticks.